About the spectrum family of the multiplication operator
Let $<,>$ be the inner product of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.
For a measurable function $F:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$, we define
a multiplication operator $M_F:L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)\to L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$, whose domain of definition
$D\left(M_F\right):=\left\{f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)\ \middle|\ \displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|F(x)\cdot f(x)|^2dx<\infty\right\}$,
$M_Ff:=F\cdot f\ \ \ (f\in D\left(M_F\right))$.
For $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, we define
$\chi_{F^{-1}((-\infty,\lambda])}:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R},\ x\mapsto\begin{cases}1\ \ (F(x)\in(-\infty,\lambda])\\0\ \ (F(x)\notin(-\infty,\lambda])\end{cases}$,
and a multiplication operator $M_{\chi_{F^{-1}((-\infty,\lambda])}}:L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)\to L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$, whose domain of definition
$D\left(M_{\chi_{F^{-1}((-\infty,\lambda])}}\right)=\left\{f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)\ \middle|\ \displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|\chi_{F^{-1}((-\infty,\lambda])}(x)\cdot f(x)|^2dx<\infty\right\}=L^2(\mathbb{R}),$
$M_{\chi_{F^{-1}((-\infty,\lambda])}}f:=\chi_{F^{-1}((-\infty,\lambda])}\cdot f\ \ \ \left(f\in D\left(M_{\chi_{F^{-1}((-\infty,\lambda])}}\right)\right)$
, and
the spectrum family $E_F:\mathbb{R}\to\{P:L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)\to L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)\text{, projection}\}$, $\lambda\mapsto M_{\chi_{F^{-1}((-\infty,\lambda])}}$.
We define a self-adjoint operator $A_{E_F}:L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)\to L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$,  whose domain of definition $D(A_{E_F}):=\left\{f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)\ \middle|\ \displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\lambda|^2d<f,E_F(\lambda)f>\right\}$,
$A_{E_F}f:=\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}}\lambda dE(\lambda)f\ \ (f\in D(A_{E_F}))$.
I want to prove that $D(M_F)=D(A_{E_F})$ and $M_F=A_{E_F}$ on $D(M_F)$.
Please, teach me it.

This is literally just a special case of the spectral theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Unbounded_self-adjoint_operators

Also, the multiplication operators associated with indicator functions $\chi_{F^{-1}((-\infty, \lambda])}$ are bounded, so their domains are just $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$. You’re writing this in a far more complicated way than necessary.

Thank you for comments. I have read the proof of the spectral theorem, but I don't think of an answer.  I correct the domain of definition.

It seems like I can understand it through a variable transformation in Lebesgue integration, but I'm not sure.

Well, again, what you asked is exactly the statement that the multiplication operator version and the projection-valued measure version of the spectral theorem are equivalent. If you have read the proof of the spectral theorem but cannot realize the connection, you might have missed one of the versions and I’d suggest going back to make sure you have read and understood the proof of both versions.

Regardless, I have supplied an answer giving a direct proof using Fubini.

Thank you very much for the direct proof.
Why is it that $\int_\mathbb{R} |\lambda|^2 , d\langle f, E_F(\lambda)f\rangle = \int_0^\infty \mu({\lambda: |\lambda|^2 \geq r}) , dr$?

This is one of the ways the Lebesgue integral is defined, namely, for a positive function $f$ and a (positive) measure $\mu$, $\int f , d\mu$ is defined as $\int_0^\infty \mu({\lambda: f(\lambda) \geq r}) , dr$ where the latter integral is an (improper) Riemann integral. Though if you define Lebesgue integrals differently, you can still easily prove this using Fubini-Tonelli. Indeed,$$\int f , d\mu = \int \int_0^\infty \chi_{{r \leq f(\lambda)}} , dr , d\mu = \int_0^\infty \int \chi_{{r \leq f(\lambda)}} , d\mu , dr = \int_0^\infty \mu({\lambda: f(\lambda) \geq r}) , dr$$

I understand this comment. And,
\begin{align*}
\int_\mathbb{R} |\lambda|^2 , d\langle f, E_F(\lambda)f\rangle
= \int_\mathbb{R} |\lambda|^2 , d\langle f, \chi_{F^{-1}((-\infty,\lambda])}\cdot f\rangle
=\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\lambda|^2\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\chi_{F^{-1}((-\infty,\lambda))}(x)|f(x)|^2dxd\lambda
= \int_{\mathbb{R}}|\lambda|^2\int_{F^{-1}((-\infty,\lambda]))}|f(x)|^2dxd\lambda
=\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\lambda|^2\mu((-\infty,\lambda))d\lambda.
\end{align*}

Therefore, my question is why $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\lambda|^2\mu((-\infty,\lambda))d\lambda = \int_{\mathbb{R}}|\lambda|^2d\mu(\lambda)$.

I’m honestly confused with what you wrote. The second equality you wrote down is just wrong. It seems you are misunderstanding what integral w.r.t. $d\langle f, E_F(\lambda)f \rangle = d\langle f, \chi_{F^{-1}((-\infty, \lambda])} f \rangle$ means. It is integral w.r.t. the measure $\mu$ defined by the formula in my answer, and not multiplying by $\int \chi_{F^{-1}((-\infty, \lambda])}(x)|f(x)|^2 , dx$ and then integrate w.r.t. Lebesgue measure. These are very different things. (Recall from elementary calculus that $\int f(x) , dg(x) = \int f(x)g’(x) , dx$, not $\int f(x)g(x) , dx$.)

The general version of this, without assuming differentiability, is known as Lebesgue-Stieltjes integrals: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integration

Yes, I'm wrong.
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\lambda|^2 d\left\langle f, E_F(\lambda) f\right\rangle
=\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\lambda|^2 d\left\langle f, X_{F^{-1}((-\infty, \lambda])} \cdot f\right\rangle
=\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\lambda|^2 d\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} X_{F^{-1}((-\infty, \lambda])}(x) \cdot|f(x)|^2 d x\right)
=\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\lambda|^2 d\left(\int_{F^{-1}((-\infty, \lambda])}|f(x)|^2 d x\right)
=\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\lambda|^2 d\left(\mu((-\infty, \lambda])\right)
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
=\lim {N \rightarrow \infty}\lim {-N=\lambda{-n}<...<\lambda{n}=N, \max \left|\lambda_{i+1}-\lambda_i\right| \rightarrow 0, n \rightarrow \infty}
\sum_{i=-n}^n\left|\lambda_i\right|^2\left(\mu\left(\left(-\infty, \lambda_{i+1}\right]\right)-\mu\left(\left(-\infty, \lambda_i\right]\right)\right)
=\lim {N \rightarrow \infty}\lim {-N=\lambda{-n}<...<\lambda{n}=N, \max \left|\lambda_{i+1}-\lambda_i\right| \rightarrow 0, n \rightarrow \infty}
\sum_{i=-n}^n\left|\lambda_i\right|^2\mu((\lambda_{i+1},\lambda_i])
\end{align*}

Otherwise,
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\lambda|^2 d\mu(\lambda)
= \lim {N \rightarrow \infty}\lim {-N=\lambda{-n}<...<\lambda{n}=N, \max \left|\lambda_{i+1}-\lambda_i\right| \rightarrow 0, n \rightarrow \infty}
\sum_{i=-n}^n\left|\lambda_i\right|^2\mu({x|\lambda_i<|x|^2\leq \lambda_{i+1}})
\end{align*}
Is it correct that $\left|\lambda_i\right|^2\mu((\lambda_{i+1},\lambda_i]) = \left|\lambda_i\right|^2\mu({x|\lambda_i<|x|^2\leq \lambda_{i+1}})$ ?

Of course not. Why should it? If $\lambda_{i+1} < 0$, the second set is literally empty. Even if both $\lambda$ are positive, you are basically saying $\mu((\lambda_i, \lambda_{i+1}]) = \mu((\sqrt{\lambda_i}, \sqrt{\lambda_{i+1}}]) + \mu([-\sqrt{\lambda_{i+1}}, -\sqrt{\lambda_i}))$, which isn't even true when $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure, say.

You're just confusing yourself. Again, that integral in your question is literally just integration w.r.t. $\mu$, by definition. I don't know what all these follow-up questions are for. If you're confused about how Lebesgue-Stieltjes integrals are defined (which seems to be the case with all these follow-ups you're asking), you should find some reference on that to read, not just write down random stuff here and ask me to verify them. This is really not related to your original question anymore.

Thank you for all your advice. I'll try to think about it properly.

Note that integral w.r.t. $d\langle f, E_F(\lambda)f\rangle$ is, by definition, integral w.r.t. the measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$, defined by,
$$\mu(A) = \langle f, E_{\chi_{F^{-1}(A)}}f \rangle = \int_{F^{-1}(A)} |f|^2 \, dx$$
Thus,
$$\begin{split}
\int_\mathbb{R} |\lambda|^2 \, d\langle f, E_F(\lambda)f\rangle &= \int_0^\infty \mu(\{\lambda: |\lambda|^2 \geq r\}) \, dr\\
&= \int_0^\infty \int_{(|F|^2)^{-1}([r, \infty))} |f(x)|^2 \, dxdr\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |f(x)|^2 \int_0^\infty \chi_{(|F|^2)^{-1}([r, \infty))}(x) \, drdx\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |f(x)|^2 \int_0^\infty \chi_{\{r \leq |F|^2(x)\}}\, drdx\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |f(x)|^2|F(x)|^2 \, dx\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |F(x)f(x)|^2 \, dx
\end{split}$$
Thus, the conditions defining $D(M_F)$ and $D(A_{E_F})$ are equivalent, or, to put it another way, $D(M_F) = D(A_{E_F})$.
Now, onto proving $M_F = A_{E_F}$. Let $f \in D(M_F) = D(A_{E_F})$ and $g \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be arbitrary. It suffices to prove $\langle g, M_Ff\rangle = \langle g, A_{E_F}f\rangle$. Let $\mu$ be the (complex-valued) measure on $\mathbb{R}$ defined by,
$$\mu(A) = \langle g, E_{\chi_{F^{-1}(A)}}f\rangle = \int_{F^{-1}(A)} \bar{g}f \, dx$$
So,
$$\begin{split}
\langle g, A_{E_F}f\rangle &= \int_\mathbb{R} \lambda \, d\langle g, E_F(\lambda)f\rangle\\
&= \int_0^\infty [\mu(\{\lambda: \lambda \geq r\}) - \mu(\{\lambda: \lambda \leq -r\})] \, dr\\
&= \int_0^\infty [\int_{F^{-1}([r, \infty))} \bar{g}(x)f(x) \, dx - \int_{F^{-1}((-\infty, -r])} \bar{g}(x)f(x) \, dx] \, dr\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \bar{g}(x)f(x) \int_0^\infty \chi_{\{r \leq F(x)\}} \, drdx - \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \bar{g}(x)f(x) \int_0^\infty \chi_{\{r \leq -F(x)\}} \, drdx\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \bar{g}(x)f(x) F(x) \chi_{\{F(x) \geq 0\}} \, dx - \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \bar{g}(x)f(x) (-F(x)) \chi_{\{F(x) < 0\}} \, dx\\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \bar{g}(x)F(x)f(x) \, dx\\
&= \langle g, M_Ff\rangle
&
\end{split}$$
